# Chrome html 5 video failed for a link with redirection

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am doing experiment with Chrome Version 22.0.1229.79 on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

```
<video src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The chrome cancels the request if the src url will return a redirection first. While in other browsers (opera, safari, firefox), the redirection will be done and return the address of corresponding mp4 file (https://www.example.com/path/to/video.mp4).

I find a related issue http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102201.

Can anyone provide some specification about this issue or methods to handle it?

It works if replacing the html5 video tag with an **iframe**, which will do the redirection and return the mp4 file. However, there will be no way to control the video with javascript.

Comment: y are you redirecting... could u do something like the url echo's video's content

Comment: @WebDeveloper The server side implements a service.

Comment: what do u mean by service.....youtube uses iframe so i think you are fine with iframe

Comment: @WebDeveloper because you cannot run js in the iframe